# Is it possible to configure the browser for links in Notepad++?

Tags: browser, notepad++, file-association, default-settings, links

In recent versions of Notepad++, the user can enable double-clicking on HTTP and HTTPS links to open them in a browser.

By default, it opens them in the operating system's default browser.

Is it possible to specify opening the links in a different browser ***without*** changing the default browser in the OS (Windows 7)?